# Transfer CloudWatch Logs to S3 using Lambda or Kinesis Firehose?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I’m looking for a way to transfer cloudwatch logs to s3 bucket. I found I can use subscription filter in cloudwatch. I see two options.

One is CW -> Kinesis Firehose -> S3.

Other one is CW -> lambda -> S3.

Do you know which one is better? I feel like Kinesis firehose is easier to set up, but is using lambda cheaper?

Answer (score 1):

When using lambda you get charged:

- $0.20 per 1 million requests (or $0.0000002 / request)
- $0.00001667 GB-second of memory (fixed during computation)

For Kinesis you get charged:

- $0.035 per GB ingested

Lambda will always be a cheaper solution if its setup correctly.

Kinesis in the back is a lambda.

Comment: A Kinesis Firehose subscription filter on CW is quick and easy to set up. I've done that recently, and it worked for a couple days. But in my environment we have to whitelist inbound IP address ranges in our bucket policy. Kinesis does not publish their CIDR ranges. Neither does Lambda. We traced the address range from logs, and added it. But then the whole thing broke a couple days later. So now I'm moving from Kinesis to a Lambda in our VPC.

Comment: A managed solution in the beginning is an easy way. But in the end you will move that and create something custom because it was too limited/costly,...

Answer (score 0):

Sending CloudWatch Logs to S3 using Firehose is way simpler. If you do it using Lambda you will need to handle putting the object on S3 by yourself and have a retrying mechanism if something goes wrong with your Lambda. Lambda is more recommended in cases where you need to process the logs before actually sending them.

It is important to calculate the volume of log data that will be generated beforehand and based on that provision your Firehose accordingly, if you go that way.

Finally, if you don't care about the logs being sent in real-time you can also explore the [Export to S3 feature by CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/S3Export.html). You can set up a Lambda that runs periodically and creates an Export for your CloudWatch log group. This is the cheaper solution but with the downside of not transferring your logs in real-time.

Comment: You can setup events/ subscriptions to cloudwatch that have a lambda attached and have it done realtime.Everything you can do with firehose/kinesis you can also do with Lambda.
Under the hood of Firehose and Kinesis are Lambdas/ec2's